# same code producing different result on different kind of emulator

Tags: android, google-api, emulation

I am trying to create an application for android, which allows the users to send the sms from a particular website and it also allows to check them the amount credited in their account on that website. But i am facing one weird problem. The same piece of code is producing different output on different kind of emulators. That is, when in tested in on emulator with TARGET `ANDROID 2.3.3` it worked perfectly and produced the desired result but when i run the same application on emulator with TARGET `GOOGLE APIS - API LEVEL 10` i am always getting `null` as the output. Moreover i tested the application on my Android 4.0 device, even on the phone i am always getting `null` as the output. I am putting up the screenshot of the situation with the question. Can anyone connect to my computer using `TEAMVIEWER` and help me solve the error, I cannot disclose the full code here but to give the idea about it, here are the imports that i have used

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
```

and some code goes like this:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(rs);
```

The screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT:**

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
}
String text = response.toString();
int start = text.indexOf("<p>Rs</p>");
int end = text.indexOf("<div class=\"paisa_bg\">");
String rs = text.substring(start, end);
String pattern = "<h1>(\\d+)</h1>";
```

**HTTPURLCONNECTION**

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("PARAM1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("VALUE1", "UTF-8");
                data = data + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("PARAM2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(VALUE2, "UTF-8");
                data = data + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("PARAM3", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(VALUE3, "UTF-8");
                data = data + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("PARAM4", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("VALUE4", "UTF-8");
                data = data + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("PARAM5", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("VALUE5", "UTF-8");

                URL url = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/534.29 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.733.0 Safari/534.29");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
```

Comment: Cqn you show us how you use HttpUrlConnection ? This API has changed before and after FROYO. http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: @Cthulhu see the edit, i have added the details you asked for

Comment: @Snicolas please see the edit, i have added the details you asked for. is there anything wrong i am doing?

Comment: Have a look at the article I pointed to you. There might something around HttpUrlConnections

Comment: @Snicolas did you find any mistakes in the above code?? and can you please connect to my computer using teamviewer. pls

Comment: no sorry, I won't be connected before a couple of hours and I don't do this kind of things. I couldn't find any thing wrong but go on digging, you will find.